# How to remove duplicate values from an associative array based on a specific value?

Tags: php, arrays, unique, associative

I have an array that looks just like that:

```
array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["first_name"]=> string(6) "Ulrike" ["last_name"]=> string(10) "Grasberger" }

array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["first_name"]=> string(5) "Frank" ["last_name"]=> string(9) "Neubacher" }

array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(3) "896" ["first_name"]=> string(2) "D." ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Bauer" }

array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(3) "896" ["first_name"]=> string(2) "S." ["last_name"]=> string(6) "Anders" }

array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(3) "896" ["first_name"]=> string(2) "M." ["last_name"]=> string(6) "Tsokos" }

array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(3) "897" ["first_name"]=> string(8) "Reinhard" ["last_name"]=> string(8) "Scholzen" }
```

Now what I want to do is to get rid of the duplicate `"fk_article_id"` values `"896"`, so that only the first of those is left:

```
array(3) { ["fk_article_id"]=> string(3) "896" ["first_name"]=> string(2) "D." ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Bauer" }
```

I now `array_unique()` but I haven't found a possibility to tell the function to only use the values in the `"fk_article_id"` ID.

How can I do this?

Edit:

It's the output of a three column db table via:

```
$authors_result = pg_query($query_authors) or trigger_error("An error occurred.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL-Statements: {$searchSQL}");

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($authors_result)) {
var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: That looks like several arrays... do you have an array of arrays?

Comment: Can you display this as code, not as output

Comment: It's the output of a three column db table, I edited the main post.

Comment: if this is the output of a query isn't it possible to use a group by clause on the fkarticle_id field?

Comment: i've thought of this myself, but it's not possible, due to db design restrictions. it's a pretty complicated query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce) would look like:

```
$unique = array_reduce($subject, function($final, $article){
    static $seen = array();
    if ( ! array_key_exists($article['fk_article_id'], $seen)) {
        $seen[$article['fk_article_id']] = NULL;
        $final[] = $article;
    }
    return $final;
});
```

Try [a working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eOjCX4).

---

Edit: Seems you don't want to work with the aggregated results. Here are two other thoughts:

**Filtering in PHP**

```
$seen = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($authors_result)) {
    // Skip this row if we have already seen its article id
    if (array_key_exists($row['fk_article_id'], $seen)) {
        continue;
    }
    // Note that we have seen this article
    $seen[$row['fk_article_id']] = NULL;
    // Do whatever with your row
    var_dump($row);
}
```

**Filtering in the DB**

The idea here is to change the query being executed so that the repeated article ids do not appear in the result set.  How this is done will depend on the query that you're already using.

Comment: Looks pretty good, thanks! Would it be possible to use one array instead of a multi-dimensional for $subject?

Comment: You're absolutely right of course :) But I don't know with which pg_fetch_* function I can get exactly the output to fit your $subject... pg_fetch_all doesn't really work. I'm a beginner, I'm sorry.. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(!in_array( $array[$key]['fk_article_id'], $usedValues)){
        $usedValues = $array[$key]['fk_article_id'];
        $cleanArray = $array[$key];
    }
}
```

something along thoose lines should do it, i don't think there is an pre existing array funciton for that

Answer (score 0):

I would use a foreach-loop to iterate over the arrays and save all arrays that dont have a duplicate _id to a new array.

```
$clean = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  if (!isset($clean[$array['fk_article_id']])
    $clean[$array['fk_article_id']] = $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to iterate over the array, copying ownly the first instance of each fk_article_id in a new array.

```
<?php

$your_unique_array = array();
foreach ($your_original_array as $v) {
  if (!isset($your_unique_array[$v['fk_article_id']) {
      $your_unique_array[$v['fk_article_id'] = $v;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

** get Unique Associative Array **
using this method you can get easily unique Associative array /Multidimensional  Array.

```
  array:6 [▼
     0 => array:1 [▼
       2 => "Airtel DTH"
           ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
      2 => "Airtel DTH"
           ]
      2 => array:1 [▼
      2 => "Airtel DTH"
           ]
      3 => array:1 [▼
      3 => "NeuSoft PVT LMT"
      ]
       4 => array:1 [▼
      3  => "NeuSoft PVT LMT"
       ]
      5 => array:1 [▼
       3 => "NeuSoft PVT LMT"
       ]
      ]


     function  assoc_Array_unique($array)
            {
                $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

                foreach ($result as $key => $value)
                {
                    if ( is_array($value) )
                    {
                        $result[$key] = assoc_Array_unique($value);
                    }
                }
                return   $result;
            }
   $arr_Company=   assoc_Array_unique($arr_Company);  // get Unique Array 
                $arr_Company = array_values($arr_Company); Rearrange Index of Array.
```