# Remove duplicated elements of associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$result = array(
    0=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'Hello'),
    1=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'other'),
    2=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'other'),
);
```

If it is duplicated removed it, so the result is as follows:

```
$result = array(
    0=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'Hello'),
    1=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'other')   
);
```

Could any know to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What makes it duplicate `a=` & `b=other` or just `b=other` ...

Comment: `a` and `b` @Bada thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767318/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-associative-array-based-on-a-specific-val

Answer (score 94):

Regardless what others are offering here, you are looking for a function called [`array_unique`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_unique). The important thing here is to set the second parameter to `SORT_REGULAR` and then the job is easy:

```
array_unique($result, SORT_REGULAR);
```

The meaning of the `SORT_REGULAR` flag is:

> compare items normally (don't change types)

And that is what you want. You want to [compare arrays<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.operators.array) here and do not change their type to string (which would have been the default if the parameter is not set).

`array_unique` does a strict comparison (`===` in PHP), for arrays this means:

> `$a === $b` `TRUE` if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.

Output ([Demo](http://eval.in/4529)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => Hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => other
        )
)
```

Comment: cool, didmt know that a second parameter is availible at al.l

Comment: @DavidMüller: The manual is always worth a visit ;) At least that's how I do it if it is getting specific. You can not know each function in-and-out.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me. I am still getting duplicate results on this.

Comment: In addition to this solution, you can do array_values() to rebase your array keys. Just by doing array_values(array_unique($result, SORT_REGULAR));

Answer (score 30):

First things first, you can not use plain `array_unique` for this problem because array_unique internally treats the array items as strings, which is why "Cannot convert Array to String" notices will appear when using array_unique for this.

So try this:

```
$result = array(
    0=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'Hello'),
    1=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'other'),
    2=>array('a'=>1,'b'=>'other')
);

$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $result)));

print_r($unique);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => Hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => other
        )

)
```

Serialization is very handy for such problems.

If you feel that's **too much magic** for you, check out this [blog post](http://floern.com/webscripting/array-unique-f%C3%BCr-multidimensionale-arrays)

```
function array_multi_unique($multiArray){

  $uniqueArray = array();

  foreach($multiArray as $subArray){

    if(!in_array($subArray, $uniqueArray)){
      $uniqueArray[] = $subArray;
    }
  }
  return $uniqueArray;
}

$unique = array_multi_unique($result);

print_r($unique);
```

Ironically, `in_array` is working for arrays, where `array_unique` does not.

Comment: Well, actually `array_unique` is fine. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13860140/367456

Comment: This is THE answer if you want the result in the same format as the input (without integer keys).