# how to sum array values if product_id same?

Tags: php, arrays

How to sum array values if products id same? I need sum product_price, quantity, total_price, shipping_price. This is my example

```
[936] => Array
        (
            [order_number] => 936
            [status] => cancelled
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 19
                            [sku] => sku2222222
                            [product_price] => 12.00
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [total_price] => 17
                            [shipping_price] => 5.00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 19
                            [sku] => sku2222222
                            [product_price] => 12.00
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [total_price] => 17
                            [shipping_price] => 5.00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 5
                            [sku] => sku2222222
                            [product_price] => 12.00
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [total_price] => 17
                            [shipping_price] => 5.00
                        )

                )
        )
```

Comment: pls share required result format

Comment: `for` loop will help.

Comment: You can do select update delete operation using PHP LINQ pls look https://phplinq.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples url for more info

Comment: this is results what i need http://paste.ofcode.org/zeRZfLwDKj7btTtn2KSnmZ

Comment: sure on multiplicating `product_price`? ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicated elements of associative array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857775/remove-duplicated-elements-of-associative-array-in-php)

Comment: i dont need remove dublicate, but sum dublicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `for` loop to sum all needed variables.

```
$orders = array(
    936 => array(
        "order_number" => 936,
        "products" => array(
            array(
                "product_id" => 19,
                "total_price" => 17,
                "shipping_price" => 10
            ),
            array(
                "product_id" => 19,
                "total_price" => 17,
                "shipping_price" => 10
            ),
            array(
                "product_id" => 5,
                "total_price" => 17,
                "shipping_price" => 10
            ),
        )
    )
);

foreach ($orders as $order_id => $order) {
    $order_products = array();
    foreach ($order['products'] as $product) {
        if (isset($order_products[$product['product_id']])) {
            $order_products[$product['product_id']]['total_price'] += $product['total_price'];
            $order_products[$product['product_id']]['shipping_price'] += $product['shipping_price'];
        } else {
            $order_products[$product['product_id']] = $product;
        }
    }
    $orders[$order_id]['products'] = $order_products;
}

print_r($orders);
```