# Remove elements from associative array with two matching sub values

Tags: php, duplicates, associative-array

Using the example below, how can I remove all duplicate top level array elements that meet the following criteria:

- same TicketID_xxxxx and Ticket_Reply_xxxxx numbers (where xxxxx is the number)
- also have matching timestamps?

**Edits for additional info:**

- I will always need to remove the sub-array with TicketID_xxxxx while
  keeping the sub-array with Ticket_Reply_xxxxx

**Starting array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 07:43:15
            [1] => TicketID_25500
        )

     [1] => Array
         (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 08:00:00 //matching timestamp
            [1] => TicketID_25500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 08:00:00 //matching timestamp
            [1] => Ticket_Reply_25500
        )
}
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 07:43:15
            [1] => TicketID_25500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 08:00:00
            [1] => Ticket_Reply_25500
        )
}
```

Comment: You can try  `array_unique();`

Comment: Not sure if `array_unique()` would work for this array as your output will be the same as the input (for the above example). Fails on the timestamp for array[0] and array[1] because timestamps are different

Comment: In your example: How do you know which one you need to keep between `[1]` and `[2]` from the "starting array"?

Comment: @Mr.Developer I tried some of the methods in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857775/remove-duplicated-elements-of-associative-array-in-php , but that topic is focused on all sub values matching. Could you give an example how I can use array_unique() in this case?

Comment: @cbaconnier I will always need to remove the TicketID_xxxxx while keeping the Ticket_Reply_xxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SORT_REGULAR` option More doc is [HERE](http://php.net/array_unique) about `array_uniqy()`

```
    <?php

$result = array(
    0=>array(0=>'2018-03-03 07:43:15',1=>'TicketID_25500'),
    1=>array(0=>'2018-03-03 08:00:00',1=>'TicketID_25500'),
    2=>array(0=>'2018-03-03 08:00:00',1=>'Ticket_Reply_25500'),
);

$details = unique_multidim_array($result ,'1'); 
print_r($details);
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
}
```

O/P is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 07:43:15
            [1] => TicketID_25500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-03-03 08:00:00
            [1] => Ticket_Reply_25500
        )

)
```

**Edited**:

```
`unique_multidim_array($result ,'1');`
```

This Function is passing a two params. one is array and another one is the key for the Unique values.

In explanation of checking the array key value is already exist or not

`if(!in_array($val[$key], $key_array))`

If that Value and key not in array going to return the array else it ejects like:

```
    $temp_array[$i] = $val;
return $temp_array;
```

You can change the `Key` for your convenience like 'Numeric key' or 'String key'
like `unique_multidim_array($result ,'a');` or `unique_multidim_array($result ,'b');`.

Comment: You misread his data. The 3rd array element 2 is `Ticket_Reply_25500` and you have `TicketID_25500`. As I said previously in another comment.. `array_unique` will not work with this data

Comment: Good, output is solid too. Well done. Might want to go into more detail about what you've done tho as this could be quite confusing method if you're new to PHP

Comment: @Nawin Thank you much! Would you mind adding a few comments to your code and an example how to call the function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) using both TicketID and Ticket_Reply.

Comment: @Nawin I'm marking this as the accepted answer. My array is actually quite a bit more complicated, but this worked well during initial testing.

Comment: I don't know well English But i tried my best for the explanation @linweb

Comment: @Nawin Your added comments helped me a lot. Thank you for adding the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you.

```
<?php

$a = array( 
    array("2018-03-03 07:43:15","TicketID_25500"),
    array("2018-03-03 08:00:00","TicketID_25500"),
    array("2018-03-03 08:00:00","Ticket_Reply_25500"),
    array("2018-03-03 08:03:00","Ticket_Reply_25500"),
);

function array_multi_unique($multiArray){
    $all = array_column($multiArray,1); // pass 0 for timestamp
    $unique = array_values(array_unique($all));

    foreach($unique as $key){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($multiArray as $k => $v){
            if(in_array($key,$v)){
                if($i != 0){
                    unset($multiArray[$k]);
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    $multiArray = array_values($multiArray);
    return $multiArray;
}

$unique = array_multi_unique($a);
print_r($unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to

1. Define a class (assume A) that implements Hashtable so that you have your own equals method. The data members of this class will be ticket id and timestamp.
2. Instantiate a [php set](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) 'uniqueEntries'.
3. Instantiate an array 'duplicateIndexes'.
4. For each item in your array

   - Iterate through the array to create an instance of class A, with ticket id 
     and timestamp of the object.
   - Check if the Set contains this object.
   - If it does not, add this new object in the Set.
   - If it contains the same object, then note the current iteration count in the duplicateIndexes array.
5. Now remove the elements from array whose index exists in duplicateIndexes.

Comment: I prefer a method without using a class unless a full example is provided as I'm not proficient in PHP:Classes. Thank you much though, I will research this more.